# About liquid-liquid phase transitions in binary mixtures

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, liquid-state

Suppose we have a binary mixture, this is, two substances that are miscible. When you only have one substance, you can draw a phase diagram like this one drawn by *Lawrie.skinner - Own work, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=6050596*

[image]

My question is regarding when you have a mixture of liquids that are miscible and then you have the spinodal decomposition. What would refer to liquid 1 and liquid 2 in that case? I understand that the red line is the state where both liquids are well mixed. Am I wrong? Because if so, why is it so important the binary decomposition around the critical point? Where is the typical image of the Temperature-amount of one or other substance in that plot? just in the critical point?